# Outlook Macro To Replace Com Addin

Tags: vba, outlook, save, sendmail

I'm currently looking at options to replace a Com addin I had programmed to store sent and recieved emails. As MicroSoft has decided Com Add ins will no longer be supported with the new version of Outlook, I need an alternative. I don't do the programming myself, instead, a developer is attempting to convert the solution from Com add in to Web add in, and is so far drawing a blank due to the differing ways which the two allow the saving of the msg file and their format.

Whilst the developer wrestles with that challenge I need to understand what's possible as an alternative to fulfill the following steps when saving recieved emails, and saving emails that are sent, so if anyone can give advise on how I could automate the following steps I would really appreciate it:

**Sending emails**

1. The user composes an email
2. The user clicks a macro enabled **send email** button
3. The macro reads the windows clipboard picking up a reference and address to save to on a local drive
4. The macro stamps a reference at the top of the email body, picked up from the address on the clipboard (this will be a specific part of the address that needs to be reliably idenfitied)
5. The macro saves a copy of the email using the address from the windows clipboard (.msg) to a local drive
6. The macro sends the email to the recipient

**Receiving emails**

1. The user receives an email
2. The user clicks a macro enabled **save email** button
3. The macro reads the windows clipboard picking up a reference and address to save to on a local drive
4. The macro stamps a reference at the top of the email body, picked up from the address on the clipboard (as with the above process)
5. The macro saves a copy of the email using the address from the windows clipboard (.msg) to a local drive

If someone can let me know if this is at all possible, and if they can point me to where I can learn/understand/get examples of how I could write this macro I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Outlook (Monarch) does not expose macros. Web addins is the only way you can programmatically interact with it.

The new outlook does **not** replace regular desktop Outlook, it is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar. The Office suite and Outlook in particular are very much supported.

Comment: Many thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko, this is a relief. I think the misunderstanding is due to the new 'Try New Outlook' option in the current version of Outlook. This excludes Com add in's which was the cause of my looking for advice. Thank you for responding, much appreciated.